# How to check whether the received intent contains String or int

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

My activity *receives two `intent`* from *two **different*** `activity`.

One `intent` contains `int` value with *extras* and another contains `String`. I want to distinguish both `intent` in **receiver activity**.

Is there any way to check if the received intent has `int` value in extras or `String`?

Please *don't suggest* to use `startActivityForResult()` to receive multiple intents in same activity.

Comment: Why down vote? Any explanation could be better.

Comment: are you still facing a problem with my answer ? By the way it wasn't me who downvoted you :)

Comment: @ZygoteInit I know it's not you down voted, you suggested the use of `hasExtra()` was really nice, but it doesn't solve my issue. I couldn't differentiate between received intents using `hasExtra()` that's why I had to unaccept. Btw I used `startActivityForResult()` to get it done.

Comment: I see ... no problem, good for you ... best :)

Comment: Have you ever faced [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30473371/3287204) ?

Comment: @Y.S. yes, once I had same problem, but with linux terminal; searching over the internet I came to know that terminal or any other command line doesn't accept `%20` on behalf of a single space. Simply remove %20 or put `-` *(yes linux terminal accepts `-` for space)* to get rid of that error.

Comment: that's right :) I found that out today the hard way after wasting a lot of time ... got the answer, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to differentiate between the *datatype* of the extras in an `Intent`. All you have is the [`hasExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra%28java.lang.String%29) method, and with it you can try differentiating between the datatype if you know the *name* of the extra:

```
if(intent.hasExtra("number")){
    // int
}else if(intent.hasExtra("name"))
    // string
}
```