# Unable to open DDMS in Android Studio. Mysterious Eclipse error pops up

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, ddms, android-sdk-tools

So here I go again with yet another Android Studio tools error. I don't think this one has been reported before, I can't find any posts on it.

I am trying to open the Device Monitor (DDMS) in Android Studio by clicking on the following button:

[image]

Every time I get the same error. What's really puzzling is that its an Eclipse error, as shown in the image:

[image]

So it tells me to open a log file in the Android Studio SDK folder. The log file contains lots of text, but the main error is reported as:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-05-27 09:40:53.091
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.io.IOException: The folder "C:\Users\JOHN%20SMITH\.android\monitor-workspace\.metadata" is read-only.
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.lock(BasicLocation.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:164)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:137)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:53)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Why am I unable to open DDMS from Android Studio, and why is an Eclipse error thrown when trying to open DDMS from Android Studio ? Can anyone guide me ? Has anyone even *seen* this error before ? All responses will be gratefully appreciated.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by [Daniel Nugent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4409409/daniel-nugent) in the comments below, the DDMS shipped with Studio seems to be exactly, *exactly* the same as the one in Eclipse. Wonder if this is a clue to the problem. And for the record, I do have Eclipse installed on my PC for maintaining some legacy code.

**EDIT 2:**

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424533/android-ddms-monitor-does-not-start-if-user-profile-contains-a-space-in-it/18876626#18876626). Many, many thanks to [Skizo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4385913/skizo) and [Blackbelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501696/blackbelt) for this, both of you were spot-on!

Comment: from first use itself it show error ?

Comment: well, yes. I don't recall being able to open DDMS from Android Studio.

Comment: could you try this one ,go to : \sdk\tools and open monitor.bat

Comment: good idea, I just tried that and it gives the exact same error.

Comment: well..just one more try..change the location of your adt..move to some other drive where there is no read-write restriction..Thanks

Comment: That is very interesting.  I had never used that button before, but I was able to successfully open `Android Device Monitor`.  This is on a Linux machine that has never had Eclipse installed on it.  I went to the About box of `Android Device Monitor`, and there is a link to Eclipse.org, and if you click on `Installation Details`, all of the components have eclipse in the name.  It appears that the same old Eclipse DDMS is included in the Android Studio installation, very interesting!

Comment: @DanielNugent: I have to keep Eclipse installed for a while longer, until we finish the migration to Studio entirely. So no dice.

Comment: @Y.S. Yes, it's definitely very interesting!   Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve your issue though.  Good luck!

Comment: @DanielNugent: thanks for your time. I'm always glad to oblige and entertain :)

Comment: this `%20` looks strange. It is like the the space encoded, but usually windows (not a big fan/not very experienced) deals good with space. So my hard guess is that it is pointing to a not existing location on your machine. Is there on windows the possibility to make a symlink of `JOHN SMITH` to `JOHN%20SMITH`?

Comment: @Blackbelt: many thanks, you were absolutely on the right track :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is about your `%20` in your name, then you can try it out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18876626/4385913), it seems like yours :

> I've just come across this problem too. My workaround was to create a symbolic >directory link from "Test%20User" to "Test User".
>
> 1. Open a command prompt as administrator. (shift+ctrl+(enter or click) on the >icon will do this)
> 2. cd C:\Users
> 3. mklink /d "Test%20User" "Test User"
> 4. Launch monitor.bat and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you must run the application (android Studio) with a administrator permission

Comment: You should put some print screens to teach him how to do this.

Comment: it is so easy open it as administrator (ctrl+shft+enter) to the android Studio